# What information should be put in the "How to Ask" block at questions/ask?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blocks

During the discussion at [Numeric version tags considered ... OK](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok), the idea came up to put some more hints into the How to ask block on the right side of the ask question form.

The current text is (from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

---

How to Ask

Is your question about the Drupal CMS?

We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

Provide details. Write clearly and simply.

If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

---

See [What information should be given when asking a question?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/which-information-should-be-given-when-asking-a-question) for a related question, but this is specifically about what to put in that block (which can be based on the other question).

Based on the discussion and the linked issue, two things come to my mind.

- Something like "Remember to report the Drupal version and relevant modules you are using."
- And maybe something about code.. "If your question is about code, provide the relevant pieces."

But those are pretty long sentences (typical german-english ;)), maybe someone has something shorter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok changed to

> **Is your question about the Drupal CMS?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Remember to report the Drupal version and relevant modules you are using. If your question is about code, include the relevant parts.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://example.com)** instead.
>
> [read the faq »](/faq)

Comment: Looks good to me and doesn't seem to be too cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the content of that block has a limited length or not; in any case, it doesn't seem possible to report in few words what the question text should contain, or which tags should be used.

With the experience I have with the Drupal.org site maintainers issue queue, I can say that even a simple text of few lines is not read, as periodically there are users who reports issue  or have questions for their own site, when the text clearly states that issue queue is for problems on drupal.org.

Rather than text, apart the already existing one, I think it's preferable to add the links two FAQ posts: [What information should be given when asking a question?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/which-information-should-be-given-when-asking-a-question) and another one about the tags to use.
The posts about the tags to use is still to be written, but everybody can create it. Once the question has been created, I can convert it to CW, and add [faq](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), which can only be added from moderators, which are the only ones who can change a question to CW (which means there is somebody else who can do it).

Comment: hmm, this is a good idea, but I think having one sentence on the screen is more likely to be read than requiring the user to click a link *then* read. We can do both of course, but I think Berdir's text is pretty good start.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood If a link can be added, it could a link to the "FAQ index;" two links for the specific FAQ questions would be preferable, if it is possible to add them to the block content as it is now.