# Expand the content of the "How to Ask" block

Tags: feature-request, blocks

The content of the [How to Ask](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) block that is currently shown is the following one:

> **Is your question about the Drupal CMS?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Remember to report the Drupal version and relevant modules you are using. If your question is about code, include the relevant parts.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com)** instead.

May it be expanded to contain the following text?

> **Is your question about the Drupal CMS?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Include the information suggested in **[Which information should be given when asking a question?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/which-information-should-be-given-when-asking-a-question)**
>
> Bugs and security issues should be reported on the appropriate channel on **[Drupal.org](http://drupal.org)**. See **[How to report a security issue](http://drupal.org/node/101494)**.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com)** instead.

I wrote the content using HTML, as I don't know if it is possible to use Markdown when entering the content of that block. I apologize if that is not the more appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

Your intentions are good, but that's becoming a wall of text.

Key points are:

1. Q&A, not discussion
2. Include version, modules, and relevant code (if any)
3. Bug reports go on drupal.org
4. Security issues go... somewhere else.
5. Meta topics go on meta.

**Summarize** those in a clear, friendly manner.

Comment: Is there any problem, if the block contains links to sites external to Stack Exchange?

Comment: Not if it's clear from the context or link *why*

Comment: If it is preferable, I can write a [meta-tag:faq] question here reporting what the external page says. In this way, the block would not contain a link to an external page that is not accessible when drupal.org is off-line for any reason.

Comment: If you're going to do that, strive to communicate why you're sending folks off-site *at all*. In other words, don't mirror Drupal.org, explain how Drupal.SE and Drupal.org fit together.

Comment: Is there any other change that needs to be done?